# How can I show the products or records from a specific user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ruby on rails and would appreciate any help.

I am making a web page and I want that on the homepage each user can see only the recordings or products that he has made. The user can see only his own creations on that page.

But there is one of the pages in which I have to show all the information in the database no matter the user that is logged in.

Comment: You can use cancancan gem https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan to manage permissions.

Comment: The problem is that there are other pages where I want to show the records of all users and that all users can see it. It is in only one page that I want to show the recordings of the user that is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a creation model linked to a Has Many / Belongs to relationship to your user, and a current_user method identifying your user

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :creations
end 

class Creation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You can in two different controller actions have (only showing the actions for simplicity, names are not important):

```
def user_creations 
  @creations = current_user.creations
end 

def all_creations 
  @creations = Creation.all
end
```